# Trello API PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, trello

I am trying to integrate/replace my web edit queue into Trello.

I made an organization which is not public but have created a token for read/write access.

I haven't seen a good PHP wrapper for the Trello API (have looked at the two available and couldn't really get them up and running for my purposes.)

Anyway, what I'd like to do is provide rather rudimentary access to read and insert cards to a particular list.

I have gotten as far as using the API to return the results of a List using the following:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/lists/[mylistID]/cards?key=[myappkey]&token=[mytoken]
```

I get exactly what I want as a result, json of the cards in the list.

Now I;m trying to recreate that in PHP using CURL and I'm getting an error response of unauthorized or bad request from whatever I try in the following code:

```
$url = "https://api.trello.com/1/lists/[myboardID]/cards";
$trello_key          = 'mykey';
$trello_list_id      = 'mylistid';
$trello_member_token = 'mytoken'; 

$fields = "key=$trello_key&token=$trello_member_token&name=$name&idList=$trello_list_id";
e
# init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // make sure we see the sended header afterwards
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

# dont care about ssl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

# download and close
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$request =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

So I'm just looking to see if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong. I feel like it should be simple but I've spent a couple hours on it and I think I need some help. Let me know if you have any ideas.

{i have left out obvious references to my API key, token, BoardID etc}

Comment: I tried and first error: ` Notice: Undefined variable: name in D:\LAMP\www\a.php on line 21`. Check is `$name` defined.

Comment: sorry, we can take name out of the equation. Anyway, I think I solved it, but still looking exactly on how to parse the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually seems to work for me. I was trying to use POST instead of the default GET with CURL. Still working on parsing the response but it seems like I'm on the right track. Got an "200 OK" in the response.

```
$url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/lists/[myListID]/cards?key=[MyApiKey]&token=[myToken]';

# init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // make sure we see the sended header afterwards
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

# dont care about ssl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

# download and close
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$request =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'This is output = '.$output .'<br />';
echo 'This is request = '.$request .'<br />';
echo 'This is error = '.$error .'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/[myListID]/cards?key=[MyApiKey]&token=[myToken]';

# init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // make sure we see the sended header afterwards
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

# dont care about ssl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

# download and close
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$request =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'This is output = '.$output .'<br />';
echo 'This is request = '.$request .'<br />';
echo 'This is error = '.$error .'<br />';
```